# Unknown reason that is coming up when compiling related to incomplete type when using pointer

Tags: c

Hi so i am playing around with some of my own abstract data types and am basically creating a function set that reads values from command line and then stores them into a file which will later be sorted

Everything is going fine except one thing which pertains to the title

i have done everything correctly according to my knowledge and have even faced this problem before but it somehow smoothed itself out

so i am really not sure why this problem is coming up? as far as i have understood i am doing everything correctly, i have correctly allocated teh space and used it as it should be used, but hence the problem when i run make

```
ev@devel ~/Desktop/algorithms $ make
gcc -Wall -Werror -g   -c -o readNumbers.o readNumbers.c
gcc -Wall -Werror -g   -c -o main.o main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:21:13: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    while(i<s->count){
             ^
main.c:22:14: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       fputc(s->values[i],pfile);
              ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

thanks in advance for your help

here are my files and if you can point out where this problem seems to be hanging from or on

here is the first file readNumbers.c

```
//readNumbers implementation

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "readNumbers.h"

/*
typedef union data * Data;

union data{
   int *i;
   char *k;
};

*/


typedef struct values{
   int count;
   int *values;
}values;

Nums create(int argc, char **argv){

   int i=1;
   values *a = malloc(sizeof(struct values));
   a->count = argc-1;
   a->values = malloc(sizeof(int) * a->count);

   if(argc<2){
      printf("Not enough arguments...failed\n");
      return NULL;
   }


   while(i<argc){
      a->values[i-1]=atoi(argv[i]);
      i++;
   }

   return a;
}
```

the readNumbers.h file

```
//interface for readNumbers

#ifndef __readNum
#define __readNum

typedef struct values * Nums;
Nums create(int, char**);

#endif
```

the Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -g
OBJS=readNumbers.o main.o 

read: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o read $(OBJS)
read.o: readNumbers.c readNumbers.h

main.o: main.c readNumbers.h

clean:
    rm -f read $(OBJS)
```

and the file that is using the implementation main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "readNumbers.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){

   Nums s = create(argc, argv);
   if(s==NULL){
      printf("Something went wrong\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   FILE * pfile;
   pfile = fopen("nums","w");
   if(pfile ==NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   return EXIT_FAILURE;

   int i=0;

   while(i<s->count){
      fputc(s->values[i],pfile);
      i++;
   }
   fclose(pfile);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Seems to me that the compiler is telling you that it doesn't know enough about what a 'Nums' is to be able to tell what 'Values' is.  There's not enough information in the header file.

Comment: The compiler knows that `s` is a `Nums` struct, but it's missing what members that struct has. Move your struct definition into your header file.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that

Comment: @Evert: `Nums`defines a pointer, not a `struct`.

Comment: OT: This `a->count = argc-1;` mostly likely does not do what you expect.

Comment: whats wrong with it? the first argument is the executable and since i am scanning the arguments i dont need to also scan the executable so hence argc-1 is the count of arguments i am scanning in

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is not able to resolve the members of `struct values` you have defined in the `readNumbers.c`, hence, complaints about it as the incomplete type. You can move the definition of structure to the header file.